# PersistentDictionary<T,V> failing to create for custom struct

Tags: c#

I am attempting to use the [Microsoft PersistentDictionary](https://github.com/microsoft/ManagedEsent/blob/master/Documentation/PersistentDictionaryDocumentation.md) to create a persistent dictionary of a struct.

```
PersistentDictionary can be installed from NuGet:
    Microsoft.Database.Collections.Generic
    v2.0.3
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/ManagedEsent/blob/master/Documentation/PersistentDictionaryDocumentation.md) the following should create an instance of a PersistentDictionary.

```
[Serializable]
public struct MyStruct
{
    public bool ABoolean;
    public long ALong;
}

PersistentDictionary<int, MyStruct> pd =
    new PersistentDictionary<int, MyStruct>("PersistentDict");
```

The above throws the rather cryptic Exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    Not supported for SetColumn (Parameter 'TColumn')
    Actual value was PersistentDictionaryTrial.Program+MyStruct.
```

In the example code, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ManagedEsent/blob/master/Documentation/SystemStats.md), the struct that they define has as attributes on their example struct.

```
[Serializable](Serializable)
```

Adding the (Serilizable) creates an compile error for me.  There are examples with and without the ().

The compile error is:

```
Error   CS8124  Tuple must contain at least two elements.   
Error   IDE1007 The name 'Serializable' does not exist in the current
```

The following works correctly, leading me to believe that their is something non-compliant about my struct.

```
PersistentDictionary<int, DateTime> pd =
    new PersistentDictionary<int, DateTime>("DateTimeDict");
```

Here is the full code for reference:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Collections.Generic;

namespace PersistentDictionaryTrial
{
    class Program
    {
        [Serializable]
        public struct MyStruct
        {
            public bool ABoolean;
            public long ALong;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Works correctly
            PersistentDictionary<int, DateTime> pd1 =
                new PersistentDictionary<int, DateTime>("DateTimeDict");
            pd1.Flush();
            pd1.Dispose();

            //Fails - with exception thrown
            PersistentDictionary<int, MyStruct> pd2 =
                new PersistentDictionary<int, MyStruct>("PersistentDict");
            pd2.Flush();
            pd2.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I note that their sample using public properties, whereas yours using public fields. Perhaps just try properties, following their sample, and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Also try removing each field in turn, see which one is causing the problems?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I have tried both of those ideas.  Have tried a single `int`, `long`, `bool`.  Have tried with and without properties, with and without public, and tried making the struct `internal`.

Comment: I think [these](https://github.com/microsoft/ManagedEsent/blob/6a7643d1e25db91d45ab0fc846991322963c067c/EsentCollections/ColumnConverter.cs#L234) are the conditions your type should satisfy. Not familiar with this library or concepts so cannot help you any further, but maybe some checks there might ring a bell for you.

Comment: Adding the (Serilizable) creates an compile error. -> what is the error message?

Comment: It should be [Serializable] and not [Serializable](Serializable).  It looks correct to me.  You're using primitive types.  I'll try and check tomorrow when I have access to my development PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason struct no longer works is because the support has been removed in ManagedEsent library since version 2.0.0. This means only primitive types (int, string etc) are allowed and not complex types.

More details here:
https://github.com/microsoft/ManagedEsent/releases